# MATLAB program to find percentage zeros in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

The function needs to compute and return the percentage of 0 elements in the matrix. For example, if there are 10 zeros and 15 ones in a 5-by-5 matrix that is provided as an input to `zero_stat`, it would return 40 because 40% of the elements are zero.

```
pc1 = sum(u)/size(u,2) * 100         % Percentage of ‘1’
pc0 = 100 - pctg_1                   % Percentage of ‘0’
```

code doesn't work for
 Testing with argument(s) `[1 0;0 1]`

Comment: `100 * (1 - nnz(A)/numel(A))`